# Whats an efficient workflow for my IPython / IPython Notebook projects?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, ipython, jupyter-notebook

#### Whats an efficient workflow for my IPython projects?

#### Requirements:

- easily open notebooks from anywhere
- easily shift between many notebooks in different locations
- support the rest of my workflow (ie. version control, manipulating project files outside of IPython

#### Motivation:

If you’re like me, you often work in IPython notebooks, continually open and close many different notebooks as you wind through your work day.  Its often suggested to launch the IPYNBs from the command line with something like `ipython notebook --pylab=inline` but navigating back and forth between deeply nested dirs gets old fast.  What’s the best way to get around this?

Comment: would the downvoter like to comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use a `.bat` file!

An example of how to construct one for easy launching of IPython notebooks is shown below.  Save the file as `go.bat` and then from the command line you can execute `go “ipython_notebook’s name”` to easily launch it from anywhere. (*you can name it anything, go is just convenient.*)

Because your working dir can now be easily pointed to your project dir: The project workflow conveniently  supports some helpful operations from the command line.

- Easy git commands  -- push, pull, and version the crap out of the project
- Easy project inspection – use `start .`  to open your projects directory an easily manipulate files outside of IPython
- Easy starting of an IPython cluster by adding `pcluster start -n 4` to the `start ipython notebook` line in the batch file

Know of way to improve the workflow or a better way to do this? Let me know!

#### batch file:

```
@echo off
GOTO %1
:titanic
cd C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Kaggle\Titanic\Dups\Kaggel-Titanic
start ipython notebook --pylab=inline
GOTO END
: NB
cd C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\IPython NoteBooks
start ipython notebook --pylab=inline
GOTO END
:END
```